# Is there a phonegap or cordova plugin for braintree Apple Pay payments

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Just wondering if there is a plugin for IOS Apple Pay payments using Braintree as a processor.  I have the UI JS version working on a website, and that appears to be working for CC Payments and PayPal payments on a app that is basically a wrapper for the website.  Just wondering if there is a way to get Apple Pay also working with a Phonegap app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are plugins of Braintree for Phonegap / Cordova. Use the following links to integrate them in your Application.

https://github.com/kunlqt/Braintree-PhoneGap-Plugin
https://github.com/romk1n/PhoneGap-Braintree-iOS

Comment: Thanks.  Any documentation for that ?  Will it support Apple Pay on IOS ?